# is there a way to update or insert TADOQuery from TADOQuery1

Tags: delphi, tadoquery

i have nou 2 query´s TADOQuery and TADOQuery1 and i wouth like to update TADOQuery record´s from TADOQuery1 via code is it possible ??
they have the same field´s

Thank´s
Ml

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Clone** method like this:

```
ADOQuery1.Clone(ADOQuery2);
```

I hope this will help.